# Display success message in angular form

Tags: php, angularjs, angular

I have a laravel backend and i want to display success message in my frontend.
Below is my BackEnd controller and frontend in angular 2 . How would i be able to display the success message?

//backend

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $food = food::all()->where('id', $id)->find($id);
        if(is_null($food)){
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Dish could not be found',
                'retry' => true
            ], 404);
        }
        elseif($food->delete()){
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Dish successfully deleted',
                'retry' => false
            ], 202);
        }
        else
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'An error occured ',
                'retry' => true
            ], 404);
    }
}
```

//storing dish

```
  $food->name = $request->name;
            $food->location = $request->location;
            $food->type = $request->type;
            $food->save();
            return 'Dish Record successfully added '
```

//frontend

```
  <div class="form-group">

              <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >



                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name"> Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="food.name" name="name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="location">location</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location"  [(ngModel)]="food.location" name="location" required>
                </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">Cancel</button>
                </div>
```

//api call to delete

```
 deleteFood(id) {
    return this.http.delete('http://example.com ' + id)
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
  }
```

Comment: I would return a message from your BE so you can fetch it in your `.then` function, otherwise you could check server status `200` and display msg. Can you share your `Angular` controller code pls

Comment: @Jax, i have included the controller

Comment: Can you show the `Angular` function you use to call your api?

Comment: @Jax.. that's my function to remove food

Comment: What do you get when you log response

Comment: @Jax when i delete, i get the response " Msg:Dish successfully deleted retry: false

Comment: So why don't you use `{{response.msg}}` in your view?

Comment: @Jax, i am not really clear at your response